# How to deselected a day on calendar

Tags: flutter, table-calendar

I am creating a custom calendar with [TableCalendar package](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar), when I selected day 14 on calendar, Function `selectedBuilder` will rebuild a widget with black thicker size border, and I selected the same day 14 again, will deselected day and remove black thicker border on day 14, But I don't know how to deselect day of calendar.
How can I do this?

[image: This is my UI]

Answer (score 0):

In the below-written code, the `focusedDay` has been set as the current day (Today). If you pick any other date, then the marker will update accordingly. But if you select the same date twice / tap it twice, it will roll back to the initial day (Today). So, when we want to de-select it, we tap on it again & it'll reset.

Source code:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart";

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(home: MyWidget());
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  DateTime focusedDay = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TableCalendar<DateTime>(
              firstDay: DateTime.utc(2010, 10, 16),
              lastDay: DateTime.utc(2030, 3, 14),
              focusedDay: focusedDay,
              selectedDayPredicate: (DateTime dt) => isSameDay(focusedDay, dt),
              onDaySelected: (DateTime selected, DateTime focused) {
                focusedDay = (focusedDay == focused) ? DateTime.now() : focused;
                setState(() {});
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```